# How to stop java warning pop ups from appearing again and again

Tags: java, applet

I have a self signed application, when i load it in browser it give this warning (Do you want to run this application) each time. I don't want this pop up to appear. I have tried all the settings in java configure setting.

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Deplyment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/TOC.html) contains instructions and further references on how to properly pack and sign applets. There are also [a lot of existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+applet+security+warning+is%3Aquestion) about this topic, some of them with good and detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

> Java has further enhanced security to make the user system less
>   vulnerable to external exploits. Starting with Java 7 Update 51, Java
>   does not allow users to run applications that are not signed
>   (unsigned), **self-signed** (not signed by trusted authority) or that are
>   missing permission attributes.

**WORKAROUND**

*It is highly recommended not to run these types of applications. However if you still want to run these apps, run only if you understand the risks and implications.*

As a workaround, you can use the Exception Site list feature to run the applications blocked by security settings. Adding the URL of the blocked application to the Exception Site list allows it to run with some warnings.
Steps to Add URLs to the Exception Site list

1. Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and then Configure Java)
2. Click on the Security tab
3. Click on the Edit Site List button
4. Click Add in the Exception Site List window
5. Add url to Exception Site list
   Click in the empty field under the Location field to enter the URL

Comment: so you mean it will always appear

Comment: Warning will always be there.